# How to select CSS3 profile in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, css

I've updated Visual Studio 2010 to be able to use CSS3, but I don't see how to select the CSS3 profile. I added the Style Sheet toolbar, but that's disabled (I don't even know if that's the right place to do it). I'm still getting squigglies on CSS3 properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Style Sheet toolbar is, in fact, at least one possible way to select the CSS profile of your choosing. It was disabled because the file I was in was not part of the project. When I opened up a CSS file which *was* part of the project, the CSS toolbar became active. I then chose the CSS 3.0 profile.